# Laravel: Class not found altough composer update

Tags: php, bash, laravel, composer-php, guzzle

I am using Laravel 5.5 and just installed [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) via the bash. I did this already many times and know how to use Guzzle but this time Laravel is not finding the Guzzle Class...

I already updated the composer via `composer update` but still Larvel isn't finding my Guzzel Class.

It works always but only one time if I install the Guzzle package one more time via `php composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`. But if I run the PHP script a second time I always get `Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found`. Thats is so weird..

I tried it via `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` and `$this->client = new Client();`. Same error...
Even if I use `$this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();` it doesn't work and I get the same error...

Has anyone a clue why I get this error... And how can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class IssueInvoice extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'radlvoo:issueInvoice';
    private $client_id = "CENSORED";

    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $respone = $this->client->request('Get', "https://app.debitoor.com/login/oauth2/authorize?client_id=" . $this->client_id . "&response_type=code&lang=de-de");

        var_dump($respone);
        die();
    }
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: What's the full error code you're getting.

Comment: Do a `composer dump-autoload` and look if laravel can discover the package or not, if not try to add it's provider manually

Comment: @AshutoshSharma thats all I get...

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand I already did this as well... Same error

Comment: But I just saw I get this message as well from the bash `Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so: undefined symbol: zend_interrupt_function`

Comment: Did you tried this command `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` For Autoloader

Comment: Then `composer.phar update`

Comment: Where do I have to execute this `require 'vendor/autoload.php';``?

Comment: @AshutoshSharma Thats what I get `radlvoo@hera:~/backend.radlvoo.de$ composer.phar update
-bash: composer.phar: command not found`

Comment: Does `guzzlehttp/guzzle` show up when you do a `composer show -i`? What version? What OS are you using? Is "_the PHP script_" that uses it a Laravel script?

Comment: Nope... `guzzlehttp/guzzle` is not showing up when I execute `composer show -i`. I have an Windows 10 and yeah it is a Laravel Script @kerbholz

Comment: You could either add `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",` to your project's `composer.json` and run `composer install` or start a new Laravel project and `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` to see if that works. If that doesn't work either first fix other errors you get (ioncube) and try again

Comment: It is working in another project. Just tested 2 days ago. How can I add this to the composer.json?

Comment: And how can I fix the ioncube problem?

Comment: I have added it to: `"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "zanysoft/laravel-zip": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
    },` and executed `composer install` but now I get `Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.`

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for fixing the ioncube problem. "_Run update to update them._" Run `composer update` then

Comment: After I exectued `composer update` composer has installed `- Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.2): Loading from cache` and now it is working! - Thank you!

Comment: It is SOOOOO weird tho... Now it isn't working again... As I told you.. After the first try it isn't working again and not even installed anymore..

Answer (score 0):

Your last comment about it working, and then not working makes me think you are affected by this Composer bug:

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7268

If you are using Composer 1.6.4, it may be worth downgrading to 1.6.3 to see if it works.